# Getting a JS for-loop into a Jinja templated HTML for user selection after population in a dropdown select

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dropdown

I have a set of data called countries from a JSON file called countries.json.

This data populates a dropdown list with the id #country.

When a user selects this dropdown and selects a country, a selection for "#state" comes up.

Barring all the console.logs in here, this works to get the correct data into the console, but not into the correct select tag:

```
const selectTag = document.getElementById("state");
document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const country_change = document.getElementById("country").value;
    console.log(country_change);
    console.log(countries);
    console.log(selectTag);
    const statesArray = [];
    const Ind = countries.findIndex(e => {
      return e['name'] === country_change;
})

if(Ind != -1){
      countries[Ind]['states'].forEach(e=> statesArray.push(e['name']));
}

statesArray.forEach(e => {
console.log(e);  
const option = document.createElement('option');
option.setAttribute("value", "state.name");
  option.innerText = e;
  selectTag.appendChild(option);   
  })
});
```

The select tags are as follows:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
{% for country in countries %}
{% if profile.country == country.name %}
<option value="{{ country.name }}" selected>{{ country.name }}</option>
{% else %}
<option value="{{ country.name }}">{{ country.name }}</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
<select name="state" id="state">
{% for country in countries %}
{% for state in country.states %}
{% if profile.state == state.name %}
<option value="{{ state.name }}" selected>{{ state.name }}</option>
{% else %}
<option value="{{ state.name }}">{{ state.name }}</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

When I select a country, I would expect all the states to populate the #state select tag.

However, although the console.log does show the correct states for the user selection, this does not populate the select tag with the id #state.

At the moment I am unsure if it is because I am not creating the value for the option or not creating, but when I do try to add the value, I am unsure now what the second argument is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... this is a little embarrassing but worth the post. It is neither the JS nor the Jinja templating that is the issue. But the fact I was using Materalize CSS.

The updated JS now looks like this:

```
$('#state').on('contentChanged', function () {
  $(this).formSelect();
});

const selectTag = document.getElementById("state");
document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("change", function () {
  const country_change = document.getElementById("country").value;
  console.log(country_change);
  console.log(countries);
  console.log(selectTag);
  const statesArray = [];
  const Ind = countries.findIndex(e => {
      return e['name'] === country_change;
  })
  if (Ind != -1) {
      countries[Ind]['states'].forEach(e => statesArray.push(e['name']));
  }
  let str = "";
  statesArray.forEach(e => {
      console.log(e);
      str += `<option value="${e}">${e}</option>`;
  })
  selectTag.innerHTML = str;
  $("#state").trigger('contentChanged');
});
```

If you're using Jinja templating, then you'll need to load jQuery and Materailize in the top of the base.html for this to work.